# Is there a way to declare a type alias based on whether i get a single or multiple template arguments? Preferably without specialization

Tags: c++, c++17, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

So this code block obviously doesn't work(conditional out of statement scope:D); what i want is, if only a single template argument is passed, i set the type alias to that type, if multiple are passed i set it as a tuple of the passed in types:

```
 template <typename... Args>
 struct KeyPolicy
 {
     if constexpr (sizeof...(Args) == 1)
     {
         using KeyType = std::tuple_element_t<0, std::tuple<Args...>>;
     }
     else
     {
         using KeyType = std::tuple<Args...>;
     }
 
     static KeyType getKey(const Args&... args)
     {
         return KeyType{args...};
     }
 };
```

Comment: isnt `std::tuple_element_t<0, std::tuple<Args...>` just `Args...` ? I mean in that branch `sizeof...(Args) == 1`

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number: but `using KeyType = Args...;` is wrong (even with `sizeof...(Args) == 1`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use `std::conditional` from `<type_traits>` for this.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <tuple>

template <typename... Args>
struct KeyPolicy {
    using KeyType = std::conditional_t<
        sizeof...(Args) == 1, // condition
        std::tuple_element_t<0, std::tuple<Args...>>, // if true
        std::tuple<Args...> // if false
    >;

    static KeyType getKey(const Args&... args)
    {
        return KeyType{args...};
    }
};
```

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I was indeed replicating his example as exact as possible.

Comment: yes thats a valid strategy that I follow when I can too. Comment moved

Comment: Also exactly what i was looking for:D thank you!

Comment: @basyuni if this is the answer you were looking for, might I suggest marking it as such so that the question will be resolved. Good to see this helps you out!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`std::conditional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional), something like:

```
template <typename... Ts>
struct KeyPolicy
{
    using KeyType = std::conditional_t<sizeof...(Ts) == 1,
                                       std::tuple_element_t<0, std::tuple<Ts...>,
                                       std::tuple<Ts...>
                                      >;
 
     static KeyType getKey(const Ts&... args)
     {
         return KeyType{args...};
     }
 };
```

Care, both sides are evaluated, so you might sometime trick to do "lazy" evaluation.

Note: It currently fails with empty pack as `std::tuple_element_t<0, std::tuple<>>` is ill formed.

Comment: exactly what i was looking for! thank you.